# Jasper Exception on Jboss 5.0.1

Tags: jsp, deployment, jboss

I am getting the following exception when deploying my application to Jboss 5.0.1 :

`org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld" from JAR file "vfsfile:/opt/jboss-eap-5.0.1/server/xxxx/deploy/jbossweb.sar/jstl.jar": java.io.IOException: Permission denied`

I found the following ticket: https://jira.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-7637 . But it is not related to my issue since they talk about "unable to find file" while my case is permission denied problem.

We are deploying the same ear in another node with the same Jboss version and it is working perfectly.

I have checked jvm versions and file permissions and there are no differences between both servers.

Any suggestions about what else I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanna share something. I had the exactly same issue as you. At the end, the problem is due to the permission setting of /tmp and /root folder was corrupted. It have the possibility that after the 'jstl.jar' was unzip to the /tmp folder but jboss cannot access the file in /tmp  folder and causing that issue. You might want to checking on the /tmp and /root forder for their permission

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and permissions on the `/tmp` folder was the issue in my case. The user running JBoss must be able to write to `/tmp` or you will get this error.
After fixing permissions JBoss had to be restarted (possibly redeploy of war would have been enough but didn't test that).